# How to Check is Android Download manger enabled?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

As you know , User can be disable the Android download manager in the application manager , if app using the default android download manager , it can be crash if download manager disabled , Know my question how can to know is download manager disable or enable .
Thanks <3

Answer (score 1):

Following is the code to check if any application is enabled/disabled

```
ApplicationInfo ai = 
               getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(""com.android.providers.downloads"",0);

boolean appStatus = ai.enabled;
```